# QR reader works on phone but not with SDK

Tags: android, qr-code

Created the following photos. https://plus.google.com/photos/110072219024510812700/albums/5746888837287802097?authkey=CJXL587H74LUVA

If I decode by pointing my Samsung Galaxy S onto my laptop's screen it reads it OK. I use Quickmark's app for that. I would like process it programatically so I downloaded Quickmark's SDK and tested it with the demo app, but it could not process it.

Could somebody please help, what might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you scan with an app, you are not scanning this image, but an image of this image. That may well decode, even if this one doesn't, strangely. ZXing doesn't scan this particular image either but it reads easily from screen too.

Comment: What I do not understand is that while the SDK gets a much better image quality, since the image is not moving and is skew as when I hold the camera.

Comment: OK, That said could some body please propose a QR SDK for Windows that would be able to read the above image? I tested some and simply none of them seem to work. It's no problem if it is a licenced one since I am developing an enterprise app.

Comment: I don't think I'd worry about one particular image. The question is whether it decodes most of the kinds of images you will be decoding. zxing is the de facto (Java-based) decoder SDK.

Comment: No, sadly it is unable to decode most of the images taken on site by field service men.

Comment: Second one scans, are you sure the first is a valid QR code? It ought to be relatively easy to scan off screen but that one actually doesn't.

Comment: Yes it is valid, actually I generated it. My phone scans it.